# How do I list all files in a github repo with last editor and date?

Tags: git, github

My team works with a Visual Studio database project, using github as source control. I want to generate a report with one line for each file with the following information:

- filename;
- last action (add, modify or delete);
- last editor / committer's name;
- last edited/committed date.

I don't care which commit was involved. I just want whatever last affected the file on the master branch.

Comment: Well, this should be a simple enough script, involving `git ls-tree --recursive` with subsequent processing using `git log`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user3159253, I've tried git log / git show with --pretty="%cn, %cd"; --oneline; and --name-status. I can't seem to find options that will allow me to combine contributor name & date with filename & status. These pairs seem to be exclusive? I'm new to gitbash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function report(){
  file=$1
  #commit=$(git log -1 --pretty=%H -- "$file")
  #Edit: use the following command instead, in order to deal with file paths with a space.
  commit=$(git log -1 --pretty=%H -- "$file")
  #if you want to ignore the files unchanged since the root commit, you could use:
  #commit=$(git log -1 --pretty=%H --min-parents=1 -- "$file")
  authorname=$(git log -1 $commit --pretty=%an)
  commitdate=$(git log -1 $commit --pretty=%cd --date=short)
  commitcomment=$(git log --format=%b -n 1 $commit)
  status=$(git show $commit --pretty=%h --name-status | grep "$file" | awk '{print $1}')
  case $status in
    A ) status=Added;;
    C ) status=Copied;;
    D ) status=Deleted;;
    M ) status=Modified;;
    R ) status=Renamed;;
    T ) status=Changed;;
    U ) status=Unmerged;;
    B ) status=Broken;;
    * ) status=Unknown;;
  esac
  echo "$commit|$file|$authorname|$commitdate|$status|$commitcomment"
}

#git ls-files | while read line; do report $line; done > report.txt
#Edit:use the following command instead, in order to get all files, including deleted files.
git log --pretty="/ %h" --name-only | grep -v ^$ | grep -v "/ " | sort -u | while read line;do report "$line"; done; > report.txt
```

and then you could import report.txt into an excel, spliting the fields by '|'.

My code may be not efficient enough but it works.

Comment: First -- this is terrific. Thank you! Really impressive. I do see two problems, I think. One is that this won't work if there's spaces in the paths, which unfortunately there are, b/c Visual Studio names some of the folders, eg, 'Stored Procedures'. The second is that I don't think this will pick up deletes? This probably needs to be combined with the suggestion above to use ls-tree -r.

Comment: @Quicksilver You are welcome and very gald it helps. As to the first problem, try to update `commit=$(git log -1 --pretty=%H -- $file)` into `commit=$(git log -1 --pretty=%H -- "$file")`. And I'll do some study to the second problem.

Comment: @Quicksilver as to the 2nd problem, I make a temp solution, updating `git ls-files | while read line; do report $line; done > report.txt` into `git log --pretty="/ %h" --name-only | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^/ | sort -u | while read line;do report $line; done; > report.txt`

Comment: the line provided seems to be combining commits & file names together (sorted). It looks to be coming together, though. When I originally asked this question, I thought I was missing an easy answer. Little did I know!

Comment: @Quicksilver Commits are output in the format '/ xxxxxxx' and are filtered by `grep -v ^/` since I think no file path begins with '/<space>' ( correct me if there's any exception ). And the blank lines are filtered by `grep -v ^$` too. So we have only file paths left which are then sorted with duplicated lines being removed by `sort -u`. At last we get a full list of all files including deleted files. But you are right, I think there must be some easy answer. Mine is somehow a bit complex.

Comment: the grep -v ^/ command doesn't seem to be filtering out the extra space. I assume it's being read as white space. I'll see if I can figure out how to get it to account for an extra space.

Comment: I made some minor changes to your proc to deal with spaces in paths, and also to adjust the info returned. Can you please give me permission to edit your post with my tweaks? Then I can mark yours as the official answer. Thank you again: I would never have put this together on my own.

Comment: @Quicksilver It's okay. Please feel free to edit it as you want.